# How setup node-schedule every month

Tags: node.js, npm

I use node-schedule module in my project.

```
var ruleResetLimits = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
//ruleResetLimits.minute = new schedule.Range(0, 59, 1) //IT WORK FINE FOR EVERY 1 MINUTES 

schedule.scheduleJob(ruleResetLimits, function(){
    logger.info(ruleResetLimits);
    logger.info('MY TASK IS RUN');
});
```

How setup schedule jobs with node-scheduling every month at first day at 00:00

Answer (score 5):

This will run your command at 12:00AM on the first of every month

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 1 * *', function(){
    console.log('Your scheduled job at beginning of month');
});
```

By default, jobs will only run once.  So if you want a job to run every month then you'll have to create the job again when the first one runs.

It uses the cron-style scheduling.  There are plenty of examples online for cron configurations.  Any configuration you want to use should be pretty easy to find and most all of them will work with `node-schedule`.

Keep in mind that if you're putting one time jobs into node like this dynamically (not hard coded in the app source) then they will be lost if the server restarts for any reason.  For one time jobs I would recommend implementing a job queue with persistent storage.  Redis usually works well for this but you could also use Mongodb or a sql backend.

Comment: But I need run job only once

Comment: maybe offtop, but in general, i trust the cron more, than nodejs.
For cron, you can remove the tasks after running it

Comment: I updated the answer.  I included `j.cancle()` in the callback and it will cancel future scheduled jobs.  This will make the job run only once.

Comment: It's OK. But how disable run this job on restart server?

Comment: I updated my answer again.  If it's a dynamic job and you want it to go away when the server restarts then you don't need to do anything extra.  `node-schedule` does not have any persistence between restarts.

Comment: I just need this job not run when i restart(re-Deploy) server. Job reset some user Data monthly. And if i will do this action every restart, my users will hungry.

Comment: Just use it as is in the answer.  Hard code it into your app and when the app restarts it will still schedule it for the beginning of the month and it will only run once per month.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Maksim and Daniel,

I'm sorry but the question and answer are unclear, first Maksim asks for a job run every monthes at 0:00 on the 1st...
...then you answer some code, saying it will run only ONCE...

...Maksim then says " BUT I want it to run only ONCE!"... ???
...Daniel then says "if you want it to run once, add j.cancel()!

whaaat??

Here's the working answer:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.month = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
rule.date = 1;
rule.hour = 0;
rule.minute = 0;

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, aggregateStats);
```

note the date param set to 1 (day of month)

Answer (score 0):

with optional first argument (for seconds) as in this [link](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), cron did not run on 1st of the month; it worked once 'seconds' is included (observed on Ubuntu linux [ec2 server] !) -

```
async function monthlyJob() {
  const jobInterval = '00 0 0 1 * *'; // 1st of the month, at 00:00:00 hrs (works)
  // const jobInterval = '0 0 1 * *'; // <-- without the seconds, didnot work!
  const job = new CronJob(jobInterval,
      async () => {
        logger.info(new Date().toISOString());
      },
      null, true
    );
  return job
}
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

From "node-schedule" documentation:

> Execute a cron job every 5 Minutes = */5 * * * *

So, to run a job every month's first day, you can use this format:

```
scheduleJob('0 0 0 1 */1 *', function () {
    console.log('heeeeey')
});
```

This will run the function every first day of the month at 00:00:00.